# [Emacs], copy rectangle, C-x r M-w is undefined

Tags: emacs

I tried to copy rectangle in Emacs using `C-x r M-w`.

But it shows **`C-x r M-w` is undefined**.

What is going on?

My emacs version info:

GNU Emacs 24.2.1

Comment: `C-h w copy-rectangle-to-register` yields `C-x r r` for me. Why do you believe it should be on a combination with Meta in it?

Comment: C-x r M-w runs the command copy-rectangle-as-kill, which is an
interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `rect.el'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue with key bindings in emacs.

Comment: What programmer doesn't use Emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command was added in Emacs 24.3.  Your version is just a little too old.

- Changes in Emacs 24.3

  ** New command `C-x r M-w' (`copy-rectangle-as-kill').
  It copies the region-rectangle as the last rectangle kill.